# Xcode iOS Cocoa framework is failing to link C static library

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to link multiple C static library (libssl and testClib) to an iOS framework (dynamic lib) project to use them inside the framework's code (no need to be exposed by the compiled framework).

All seems fine to me: the target is including all static libs under "*Linked Frameworks and Libraries*", the left Xcode panel show correctly the libs (referring to the right path) and the "Build Settings" tab have correct references to "*Headers Search Paths*" and "*Library Search Paths*".

Even checking the linker command seems correct:

```
Ld /Users/<omissis>/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyFmw.framework/MyFmw normal x86_64
cd /Volumes/<omissis>/MyFmw
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
export PATH="<omissis>"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -dynamiclib 
-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator11.0.sdk 
-L/Users/<omissis>/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator 
-L/Volumes/programming/git/<project_folder>/libs -F/Users/<omissis>/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator 
-filelist /Users/<omissis> -exported_symbols_list <omissis> -install_name @rpath/<omissis> -Xlinker 
-rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks 
-mios-simulator-version-min=8.0 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/<omissis> 
-Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc 
-fobjc-link-runtime -lssl -ltestClib -lsqlite3 -single_module -compatibility_version 1 -current_version 1 
-Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/<omissis> -o /Users/<omissis>
```

To be sure about the libraries content I've manually verified that the expected symbols were available for the target architecture.

The error I receive during framework linking phase is (an extract compiling for the Simulator):

```
 Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
 "_GenerateRandomData", referenced from:
  _CreateSt in Storage.o
 "_GetBytePtr", referenced from:
  _CreateSt in Storage.o
 "_GetLength", referenced from:
   _CreateSt in Storage.o
 ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see 
invocation)
```

The same happens even changing target architecture.

Additional infos: I'm developing in ObjectiveC and using Xcode 9.0.

Comment: What does "iOS Cocoa" framework mean?

Comment: is the name XCode uses to define the template for dynamic libs packaged as frameworks in iOS